# How to decrease database connections?

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, jdbc, jndi, connection-pooling

Hi any one can explain me how to decrease database connections. Am developed one application in java and in jdbc am using connection pooling concept . but in my application am giving MaxActive=200 for this opening only 200 connection . But in my case once application started it will open 1400 database connection .. please help me how to handle .

```
  <Resource
            name="jdbc/tm4u"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
            url="jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.230:1433;databaseName=XX;User=abc;Password=****;selectMethod=cursor"
        username="abc"
        password="******"
                maxActive="200"
      maxWait ="100"

       maxIdle="10"
            />
```

above code is JNDI configuration file .

Comment: How do you know it starts 1400 connections?

Comment: so do you want to decrease this 1400 database connections to maxActive level?

Comment: AM checking the count using the query.. it always 1400+

Comment: yes. otherwise may be the database will be crashed

Comment: check, if you are closing statements and resultsets properly. And if you are giving the connections back to the pool properly after a use.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to call the close method on the connection object.

1. The best answer is to open the connection once and save the Connection object.  You open the connection when you first get a Connection object from the driver manager (DriverManager.getConnection) or from a JDBC driver specific class (SQLConnect.getConnection()).  Save this object in an instance variable in a class or a static variable if necessary.  Close the connection just before ending your application (connection.close()).
2. Implement a static instance of a class using the singleton pattern.  Open the connection in the constructor of your singleton, and save it as an instance variable.  Whenever you need the connection, call a method on the singleton object.  Call the connection.close() method in the destructor of the singleton.
3. Whenever you open a connection, call close() when you are done with all the statements from it.